# Docker container cpu percentage

Tags: docker

I was trying to extract cpu usage in percentage by individual containers by running command

```
cpu_usage_percent=$(docker stats --format "table {{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}"  -a --no-stream | grep $container_id_cm | awk '{print $2}')
```

I want to execute this command in every 1 minute but seems to be this command takes time to give output and also cpu utilization of base system increases.

Is there any way to extract cpu usage from cgroup by calculating the parameters. In cgroup there are lot of parameters which are little bit confusing.Anybody can help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The command needs some startup time to gather data and then generate events data sequentially. Its not a good one to call every minute. You should probably run it once and consume the stream

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in a single container, you don't have to dump stats for all containers:

```
docker stats --format "{{.CPUPerc}}" --no-stream $container_id_cm
```

Might make the query a bit more performant.

Comment: I have bunch of containers and I want to execute for all using loop in bash script. I m seeking help for calculating from cgroup or api data.

Comment: I wanted to calculate from cgroup cpu data or from docker api.I can get the values but no idea how to calculate cpu utilization in percentage.